# YII - Set data in dropdownlist from 2 array using CHtml::listData

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I have 2 arrays. The First array will be the key and the second will be the value. How can I make the data in dropdownlist from these arrays?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
                    echo $form->dropDownListGroup($model, 'arrival_code', array(
                        'prepend' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>',
                        'widgetOptions' => array(
                            'data' => array('1' => 'Satu', '2' => 'Dua', '3' => 'Tiga'),
                            'htmlOptions' => array(
                                'prompt' => 'Tujuan'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
                    ?>
```

I want the data will be fill from 2 arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$new_arr = array_combine($keys, $values);

echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', $select, $new_arr);
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way dude. Try reading the docs of yii. The syntax pf CHtml::dropDownList is not like that.

Comment: I am using Yii Booster. You can find it here: [link](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/)

Comment: It could be using CHtml::listData but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: This problem have been solved. I just make the associative array. Thanks.